# Importing third party scripts into React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to use a third party script (mapbox) within the React ecosystem. In traditional javascript I import the script in the  then initialise it like so:

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.js'></script>

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.xxxtoken';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([40, -74.50], 9);
```

I tried leaving the  head of my React app then in componentDidMount() im trying to initialise it but it doesn't know what "L" is:

```
'L' is not defined
```

So I need to import in the script into the component in some way so I had a look at "react-async-script" but Im not sure...

Comment: do you use  `gulp` or `webpack` or?

Comment: Yes webpack, I can get it to import the script right? But that will just apply the script to window, can I assign it to specific var?

Comment: yes, you can load a script through webpack and just Aron said below you can assign it to a var with import

Comment: [See this link](http://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)

Comment: @CerIs did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like mapbox has an npm package, so you can install it with `npm install --save mapbox` and then use it in your react component by importing it

```
import * as L from 'mapbox';

// do stuff with L here
```